# Rails, call client side function from Server response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to build an application with Ajax using remote links and js responses.

I want to know if and how to call a function that's in the client side js from the js in the server response.

An example might be:

**client Side js file:**

```
function aloha (name){
 $('#namespace').text = name
}
```

when user clicks on link and server responds with (assuming the server has user information and person is already logged in)

```
aloha("<%= @user.name %>")
```

The example is gross simplification of what I'm actually doing but the principle is the same, at the moment the client side script(only the part that calls the client side function) isn't being called(though the response is being executed).

The main reason I'm doing it this way is I'm trying to keep the server responses relatively light weight; bringing a fairly complicated function (or two) along with the response seems a bit silly which is why I'm trying to do it this way.

EDITED: added clarification regarding execution of script

Comment: When using the Network debug console, what do you see in the server's response? Do you see a response with JS?

Comment: I do, on a slightly unrelated note, quotes are being rendered as `&quot;`, but the response is arriving and being executed but the function (which contains an alert so I can tell it's being triggered) lies silent.

Comment: Is it considered as an HTML response or a Javascript response? So you confirm that you receive a response containing the desired Javascript code BUT this code is not executed, right?

Comment: The code is definitely executed because it contains jquery that changes some elements on the page before calling the client side function, and I can  defiantly see that working.

Comment: try a different implementation of the aloha function: `window.aloha = function (name) { $('#namespace').text = name }`

Comment: Will try this when I fix something else I just buggered up.

Comment: OK, I fixed my other problem and I just tried what you suggested and the alert still doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that `&quot;` thing I mentioned, I fixed that and the alert fired.
Thanks for your help, now I just need to get the actual code working.